# JIRA and filter issues with missed release date

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to create a JQL filter in JIRA where I can show all the issues that have missed their release date. Our Versions have a `Start date` and a `Release date`:

[image: list of our versions in JIRA]

Our issues then have any of these versions set and now I want to find all issues that are still open but has passed their `Release date`. I have tried looking at the Atlassian [FixVersion documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver071/advanced-searching-fields-reference-802172572.html#Advancedsearching-fieldsreference-FixVersionfixVersionFixversion) and [Function Reference](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver071/advanced-searching-functions-reference-802172575.html) (I thought I could use the `releasedVersions()` but the version is not released) but didn't find anything useful.

We are using JIRA v6.4.

It seems the [JQL Tricks Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin/server/overview) can do the job but we don't have this installed. I assume the `overDueVersions()` would be exactly what I need

Does anyone know if it is possible to view open issues that have passed their Release date (in Version)?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hack, but what about listing (Version in (name1, name2, nameN) and issue status not closed/done))? If you only have a couple of unreleased Versions you are looking at this might be possible. You also have the date which you could use as a search pentameter, such as crated after date, or closed before date.

Good luck and have fun.